# Unexpected results from an if statement within a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I am writing some JavaScript (nothing fancy - I am a noob) and when I try to log my results to the console I am getting unexpected results. The else statement kicks in way more frequently than it should. for example, I am seeing that if i=3 and j=3 =>(x1+x2=6/100) then the else statement is being called, which of course it shouldn't do as 6/100 < 1. I'm probably being really dense, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
EDIT//
Here are the logs I am getting:
Thanks for your comments, here is the log: 

0.023799999999999998
arbitrage.js:49 (3) [0.98, 0.01, 0.01]
arbitrage.js:48 0.034
arbitrage.js:49 (3) [0.97, 0.02, 0.01]
arbitrage.js:48 0.047599999999999996
arbitrage.js:49 (3) [0.96, 0.02, 0.02]   //point A
arbitrage.js:53 Hello
arbitrage.js:54 0.047599999999999996
arbitrage.js:55 (3) [0.96, 0.02, 0.02]   //point B
arbitrage.js:48 0.068
arbitrage.js:49 (3) [0.95, 0.03, 0.02]
arbitrage.js:48 0.07139999999999999
arbitrage.js:49 (3) [0.94, 0.03, 0.03] //point A
arbitrage.js:53 Hello
arbitrage.js:54 0.07139999999999999
arbitrage.js:55 (3) [0.94, 0.03, 0.03]  //point B
arbitrage.js:48 0.09519999999999999
arbitrage.js:49 (3) [0.9299999999999999, 0.04, 0.03] //point A
arbitrage.js:53 Hello
arbitrage.js:54 0.09519999999999999
arbitrage.js:55 (3) [0.9299999999999999, 0.04, 0.03]  //point B

If you look at Point A which has run through the normal if statement and then look at point B which has run through the else statement. The values for x2,x3 and hence x1 are the same. How can this run through both if and else? Also none of these should run through point B as  0.02+0.02 for example < 1.
//


export function arbitrageCalculator3Way(odds){

    let x1=0;
    let x2=0;
    let x3=0;

    let potentialMax=0;
    let maxMin=0;
    let holderCombo=[0,0,0];
    let arbReturn =0;



    for (var i=1;i<99;i++) //nearest percentage
    {
        for (var j=1;j<99;j++) 
        {

            x2 = i/100;
            x3 = j/100;

            if(x2+x3<1){

                potentialMax = (Math.min(odds[0][0]*(1-x2-x3),odds[0][1]*x2,odds[0][2]*x3));

                if(potentialMax>maxMin)
                {
                    maxMin=potentialMax;
                    holderCombo=[1-x2-x3,x2,x3];

                    console.log(maxMin);
                    console.log(holderCombo);
                    debugger;
                }



            }
            else{
                console.log("Hello");
                console.log(maxMin);
                    console.log(holderCombo);
                    debugger;
                break;
            }


        }

    }
    x1 = 1 -x2 - x3;
    arbReturn=(maxMin-1)*100;


   console.log(arbReturn);
    console.log(`${x1}   ${x2}   ${x3}`); ////hmmm error.
    debugger;
    return arbReturn;

}
```

Comment: can you post the array of odds?

Comment: When I run your loop (leaving away the body of your if clause), everything works fine, the condition is always properly evaluated as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added an edit with the console logs in.

Comment: You are both right - it works all along. I was expecting a different result because I should have been logging a different variable.